# unable to copy files from ssd to hdd in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, copy, mv, cp

I'm trying to copy media files like .mp3,.mp4, .mkv etc. from my ssd to hdd as to save time complexity of ssd but unable to do so. Everytime I try to copy or move files it shows me this error "Error while copying 'myfilename.extension'"

Comment: There is likely to be more information provided as the file copy stops. Please edit your question and fill in a COPY of it - and mark the text as CODE (Assuming Shell usage! Select text and click button in the menu above the edit "window")

Comment: Make sure the file you copy does abide the rules for that filesystem, In Linux (ext4) you can use more characters than on Windows filesystem. Please add filesystem it is on, exact filename and filesystem it goes too.Otherwise answer are going to be generic and might not be useful for you specific.